# Google forms for school election

Tags: google, google-apps, electronic-voting

I have been incharged to manage online votings at school for school president and vice president for 11th grade only. A group of us will be excluded from voting of course. We plan to use Google forms, since it's easier and it's free.

So, everyone will be required to use the school email @westschool.com  and can only vote once. Then, they will require to upload a picture of their school matric card in order to vote.

My question is,

1. how do I exclude/ban all people in charge of managing the voting process from voting.
2. do I have to assign a code for each person so that there's no way for a person to vote using two school emails of different grades. (Example, to avoid person A uses his brother's school email to vote twice)

Comment: You could manually check each entry and manually reject ineligible votes ... That's why you have the pic in there, right?

Comment: The cards will show you their grades, so you can reject the "brother's" vote, yes? And don't you have a list of all students in the grade? That's your "voter's register". You can simply reject any name not on that list.